# Save data to table without model

Tags: magento2, magento-community

[image: Database]
[image: Admin menu]
So i want to save slider_id and banner_id on muffin_bannerslider table with the purpose of tracking which slider belong to which banner and the position of the banner in a particular slider. But that table doesn't belong to any model then how should i do it . Also sorry if this topic already answered but Eng isn't my first language so to type the problem correctly to find the answer can be a challenge sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Can use `Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection`

Example:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

class Test
{
    private $resource;
    
    public function __construct(
        ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }
    
    public function save()
    {
        $dataset = [
            'slider_id' => 1,
            'banner_id' => 2,
        ];

        $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $connection->getTableName('muffin_bannerslider');
        try {
            $connection->insert($tableName, $dataset);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```